# WinExist / Activate / Restore Doing Nothing

Tags: autohotkey

whether or not I have a myexecutions chrome window open, this one doesn't do anything visible.

```
#z::
    {
      ;Check  if program is already running,  if not,  start it
      Win_Title = "My Executions - Apps Script"
      SetTitleMatchMode,1
      Win_path = "https://script.google.com/corp/home/executions"
      If(!WinExist(Win_Title) and(Win_path < > "")) {
          Run %Win_path% 
          sleep 1000
      }

      WinActivate,Win_Title
      WinRestore,Win_Title
      ;WinMove, A,,%Win_x%,%Win_y%,%Win_width%,%Win_height% ;COMMENTED OUT FOR NOW
      return
    }
```

the ideal end state is check if the window exists, if not create it, and regardless reposition it to a specific spot on my left hand monitor.

EDIT:
Ok, I found one problem there was an extra space in my <>

Now I have this, but it doesnt' activeate the executions window (the if statement works:

```
#z::
{
  ;MsgBox, "Test"
  ;Check  if program is already running,  if not,  start it
  Win_Title := "My Executions - Apps Script"
  SetTitleMatchMode,1
  Win_path := "https://script.google.com/corp/home/executions"

  If(!WinExist(Win_Title)) {
      Run %Win_path%
      sleep 1000
  }

  WinActivate,Win_Title
  WinRestore,Win_Title
  ;WinMove, A,,%Win_x%,%Win_y%,%Win_width%,%Win_height%
  return
}
```

Comment: Try using `:=`  assignments for Win_Title and Win_Path and let us know any difference . . .

Comment: Didn't do anything. I added a msgbox to test that the script is running and it does pop up, so it isn't something weird elsewhere in the sheet.

Comment: Run %Win_path% works on its own

Comment: Before the if, whaduz `MsgBox WinExist(Win_Title)` return when the window does or doesn't exist somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works now, by removing the win title calls to active and restore. Thanks!

```
#z::
{
  ;MsgBox, "Test"
  ;Check  if program is already running,  if not,  start it
  Win_Title := "My Executions - Apps Script"
  SetTitleMatchMode,1
  Win_path := "https://script.google.com/corp/home/executions"

  If(!WinExist(Win_Title)) {
      Run %Win_path%
      sleep 1000
  }

  WinActivate
  WinRestore
  WinMove, A,,-1440,144,1400,1740

  return
}
```